# What can I do to make this foreach loop run faster as it takes long time to execute?

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, for-loop, foreach

What can I do to make this loop run faster?

```
    private void accessVendorGridData()
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (var item in getAllVendorList)
            {
                item.CurrencyName = "USD";

                // Fetch Addresses in Vendor Grid
                var Addr = _vendorservice.GetAllVendorAdd().Where(x => x.vendorId == item.Id).ToList();
                if (Addr.Count > 0)
                {
                    item.VendorAddressLine = String.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}", Addr[0].Address, Addr[0].City, Addr[0].StateProvince, Addr[0].ZipPostalCode, Addr[0].CountryRegion);
                }

                // Fetch Payment terms in Vendor Grid
                var paymentTerm = _vendorservice.GetAllPaymentTerms().Where(x => x.Id == item.PaymentTermId).ToList().SingleOrDefault();
                if (paymentTerm != null)
                {
                    item.paymenttermitem = paymentTerm.Name;
                }

                // Fetch Tax Scheme in Vendor Grid
                var taxscheme = _vendorservice.GetAllTaxScheme().Where(x => x.Id == item.TaxschemeId).ToList().SingleOrDefault();
                if (taxscheme != null)
                {
                    item.TaxschemeName = taxscheme.TaxSchemaName;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _exLog.AddErrorLog(ex, "NewVendor, accessVendorGridData()");
            ModernDialog.ShowMessage(ex.Message, "Error!", MessageBoxButton.OK);
        }
    }
```

---

What can I do to make this loop run faster? I tried Parallel.ForEach but lost in between. Can somebody help?

```
private void accessVendorGridData()
    {
            foreach (var item in getAllVendorList)
            {
                var Addr = _vendorservice.GetAllVendorAdd().Where(x => x.vendorId == item.Id).ToList();
                var paymentTerm = _vendorservice.GetAllPaymentTerms().Where(x => x.Id == item.PaymentTermId).ToList().SingleOrDefault();
                var taxscheme = _vendorservice.GetAllTaxScheme().Where(x => x.Id == item.TaxschemeId).ToList().SingleOrDefault();
            }
    }
```

Comment: First thing to do is: **measure** if that loop **really** is a bottleneck, or if you just **feel** it´s slow because stepping each line through debugger takes some time. Apart from this we can´t answer that question, as we don´t know what the methods in your loop do and if those may cause bad performance. Keep long things short: use a profiler, e.g. DotTrace.

Comment: Start from dropping *materialization*: `.ToList()` but use `Any()` instead.

Comment: For an accurate answer we also need to know what is done inside `vendorservice`

Comment: `.ToList().SingleOrDefault()` into `.SingleOrDefault()` there is no need in `ToList()` when yiu want a single item

Comment: It seems you´re calling `GetAllVendorAdd` , `GetAllPaymentTerms` and `GetAllTaxScheme` on every iteration. You may consider to extract this common code out of the loop and materialize their results in a list or an array.

Comment: If `_vendorservice` uses a database: What tables and indexes does it use + what is the execution plan for all of the queries that it runs?

Comment: Please don't edit questions so that the existing comments/answers get invalidated. Always append rather than replace when making big changes like that.

Comment: Inferring from the name of method calls, it seems the GetAllPaymentTerms and GetAllTaxScheme seems to a static data, if it is indeed static move those out of your foreach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of querying at *each iteration* you can extract `vendors`, `paymentTerms` and `allTaxSchemes` from the loop as *dictionaries*:

```
private void accessVendorGridData() {
  var vendors = _vendorservice
    .GetAllVendorAdd()  
    .GroupBy(item => item.Id)
    .ToDictionary(chunk => chunk.Key, chunk => chunk.ToList());

  var paymentTerms = _vendorservice
    .GetAllPaymentTerms()
    .GroupBy(item => item.Id)
    .ToDictionary(chunk => chunk.Key, chunk => chunk.SingleOrDefault());

  var allTaxSchemes = _vendorservice
    .GetAllTaxScheme()
    .GroupBy(item => item.Id)
    .ToDictionary(chunk => chunk.Key, chunk => chunk.SingleOrDefault());

  foreach (var item in getAllVendorList) {
    var Addr = vendors.TryGetValue(item.Id, out var addrs) 
       ? addrs 
       : new List<Vendor>(); //TODO: put the right type instead of Vendor

    var paymentTerm = paymentTerms.TryGetValue(item.PaymentTermId, out var term) 
       ? term 
       : null;

    var taxscheme = allTaxSchemes.TryGetValue(item.PaymentTermId, out var scheme) 
       ? scheme 
       : null;
  } 
}
```

Your current code has

```
O(|getAllVendorList| * (|vendors| + |paymentTerms| + |allTaxSchemes|))
```

time complexity, this one has

```
O(|getAllVendorList| + |vendors| + |paymentTerms| + |allTaxSchemes|)
```

However, it's not a solution if `_vendorservice.GetXXX()` is a query to service, RDBMS etc. and you have to call it at each iteration (since data can be changed)

Comment: Thanks for the code @DmirtyBychenko... Almost everything is working fine but the section 

        var Addr = vendors.TryGetValue(item.Id, out var addrs) 
        ? addrs 
        : new List<Vendor>();

is no output.

Comment: @Abhishek Thakur: if we have a list of vendors `vendors.TryGetValue(item.Id, out var addrs) ?` we return it - `? addr`, if not (unknown `item.Id`) we return an empty list - `: new List<Vendor>();`. Please, put the right type instead of `Vendor`